# how to add the <apex:outputlink> in vf page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am creating   a login page which takes parameter username and password. Page should also have links for “New Sign Up” and “Forgot Password?”.
please help to add those two links.

```
     <apex:form>
       <apex:outputPanel layout="block">
      <apex:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-top:1em;">
      <p><b>UserName</b><br />
      <apex:inputText required="true" id="username" value="{!username}"/>
   </p>
     <p><b>Password</b><br />
      <apex:inputSecret id="password" value="{!password}"/>
       </p>
       <br/>
     <apex:commandButton action="{!Login}" value="Login" id="Login"/>
      <apex:panelGroup id="links">
      <apex:outputLink value="ForgotPassword">




         </apex:outputLink>  
    </apex:panelGroup>>
     </apex:panelGrid>
     </apex:outputPanel>
     </apex:form>
     </apex:page>
```

Comment: I have included the solution, can you please mark it correct so that it'll be helpful for others,,,,,,,, last time also i have given the solution but you did't mark it correct,,, please mark it ,,,,,,,,,,, Thanks @user30881

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

VF Page--

```
<apex:page controller="LoginPages" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" >

<apex:form >
<apex:actionFunction name="showFgtPassword" action="{!showSection}" rerender="fgtpwd"/>
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Login Page" columns="1" rendered="{!randFlag2}" >
<b>UserName</b>
<apex:inputText required="false" id="username" value="{!username}"/>
<b>Password</b><br />
<apex:inputSecret id="password" value="{!password}"/>
<apex:commandButton action="{!SignIn}" value="Sign In" id="signin"/>
<apex:pageMessages >
</apex:pageMessages>
<apex:commandLink action="{!ForgotPassword}" value="Forgot Password" onclick="showFgtPassword()"/>
<apex:commandLink action="{!SignUp}" value="Sign Up" />
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.Static_Resources}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
<apex:outputPanel id="fgtpwd">
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Forgot Password" columns="1" rendered="{!randflag}" >
<apex:inputText label="Username" required="false" id="username" value="{!username}"/>
<apex:inputText label="Email" required="false" id="email" value="{!email}"/>
<apex:commandButton action="{!GeneratePassword}" value="GeneratePassowrd" id="GeneratePassowrd" />
<apex:commandButton action="{!Back}" value="Back" id="Back" />
<apex:pageMessages >
</apex:pageMessages>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller--

```
public class LoginPages {

    public PageReference Back() {
        PageReference newPage = new PageReference('https://c.ap2.visual.force.com/apex/studloginpage');
        newPage.setRedirect(true);
        return newPage;
    }

public String UserN;
public String Emai;
    public PageReference GeneratePassword() {
           UserN = username;
           Emai = email;
           Integer len=8;
           final String chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
           String randStr = '';
        while (randStr.length() < len) {
          Integer idx = Math.mod(Math.abs(Crypto.getRandomInteger()), chars.length());
          randStr += chars.substring(idx, idx+1);
        }

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    mail.setUseSignature(false);
    mail.setToAddresses(new String[] { email });
    mail.setSubject('PDF Email Demo');
    mail.setHtmlBody(randStr);
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
    cr = [select id,password__c from credentials__c where Name=:UserN];
     cr.password__c = randStr;
     update cr;
        ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM,'your password has been successfully sent to your email.Thank you!'));
        return null;
    }


    public PageReference showSection() {
        return null;
    }
    public LoginPages(){
    randFlag=false;
    randFlag2=true;

    }

    public Boolean randflag{ get; set;}
    public Boolean randflag2{ get; set;}
    public String password { get; set; }
    public String username { get; set; }
    public String Email {get;set;}
    public credentials__c cr{get;set;}


    public PageReference SignUp() {
        PageReference signupPage = new PageReference('https://ap2.salesforce.com/a0C/e');
      signupPage.setRedirect(true);
      return signupPage;
    }


    public PageReference ForgotPassword() {
        randFlag2=false;
        randFlag=true;
        return null;
    }


    public PageReference SignIn() {

        cr = [select id,name,password__c,student__c from credentials__c where name=:username];
        if(password==cr.password__c){
        PageReference newPage = new PageReference('https://c.ap2.visual.force.com/apex/exam?id='+cr.student__c);
        newPage.setRedirect(true);
        return newPage;
        }
        else{
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,'You Have Entered An Incorrect Password'));
        return null;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: can you please mark it correct so that it'll be helpful for others,,,,,,,, last time also i have given the solution but you did't mark it correct,,, please mark it ,,,,,,,,,,, Thanks @user30881 –